# My site title in Google changed to Chinese

Tags: google-search

When I search the keyword "UKByte" in Google it used to come up with my website name, address, reviews, map, description, and 6 subpages below the main domain. Just like the results you would get if you search for "ASDA".

Now I don't have a clue what happened or how it happened but my site name description appears to be in Chinese and everything else has disappeared. I scanned the website there was no Chinese text whatsoever. Now I'm unsure what's going on; it's just in Google.

My domain name: `www.ukbyte.co.uk`

Comment: Look at the Google cache of your page.  It is all Chinese.

Comment: any idea what could be the problem for this to happen? any solutions

Comment: I think this question belongs on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Check your encoding. English text in UTF-8 comes out as Chinese when interpreted as UTF-16.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have been hacked. The hack sends Googlebot one website, which looks like a gambling website, while for you it looks normal.

The idea is that Google will rank your website for gambling as that's what it sees. When people visit from Google for those gambling rankings the hack will normally change your website to their money page or redirect the visitor to one.

All the time you are not aware of what is going on.

To test this you can register your website with Google Webmaster Tools and find the section where you can fetch as Googlebot. Fetch and see if that is also for the gambling website.

You will need to find out how you have been hacked, remove all hacks and remove the hole that let the hacker in.

And keep monitoring as you may miss something that lets them re-hack you.

And then always keep your WordPress website up-to-date and passwords strong.